# Qual è il significato di "spendibile" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Rossovermiglio* di Benedetta Cibrario ho letto:

> In viaggio di nozze andammo a Parigi.
>
> Scendemmo al Lotti e risultò evidente già dopo qualche giorno che nemmeno i cavalli avrebbero mai potuto avvicinarci. Camminavamo in faubourg St-Honoré e mentre io tentavo di respirare Parigi stipandone ogni vetrina, ogni caffè, ogni passante nella memoria, mio marito esibiva un tono annoiato e blasé, come di colui che ha tutto già visto e sperimentato; e forse i suoi amici in Cavalleria, con i loro racconti di donnine allegre e corse a Longchamps, gli avevano davvero rovinato la sorpresa; forse Francesco cercava a Parigi altre emozioni, non questi souvenir di lusso **spendibili** facilmente, al nostro rientro, nei salotti di Torino.

Ho cercato il significato dell'aggettivo "spendibile" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il suo senso in questo brano. Significa che erano souvenir che si potevano spiegare facilmente nei salotti di Torino?

Comment: Anche secondo me ha poco senso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credo che sia meglio parafrase il senso di tutto il periodo.

I suoi amici sono stati a Parigi, hanno vissuto determinate esperienze, e le hanno raccontate al marito della protagonista nei salotti di Torino.

Per questo, lui li considera come dei souvenir. Così come, quando vai in un posto esotico, compri qualche oggetto tipico sia come ricordo, sia per mostrarlo agli altri e vantartene un po', allo stesso modo lui considera queste cose: i suoi amici hanno raccontato cosa hanno provato e vissuto a Parigi per vantarsene, dissacrando un po' le emozioni di quelle esperienze, e quindi sono state declassate a meri oggetti che provano che sei stato in quel dato posto, ossia i classici souvenir.

Penso che, così come quando spendi dei soldi, vuol dire che stai facendo svolgere loro la loro funzione (comprare beni e servizi), allo stesso modo l'idea di `spendere` qui assume il significato di "adempiere alla loro funzione", che è dire agli amici "io sono stato a Parigi e ho fatto questo", per vantarsene.

In altre parole, una volta che visiti la città e fai determinate cose, è come avere un buono per farti bello con gli amici, `spendibile` appunto nel loro caso nei salotti di Torino. Lui cercava qualcosa di autentico, non delle esperienze degradate ad oggetti da mostra.

Comment: Quindi "spendere" nel senso di "usare, utilizzare, impiegare", un po' come quando si dice "spendere qualche parola su un argomento" (esempio tratto dal Treccani)?

Comment: @Charo: Hai sintetizzato in una sola frase tutta la mia risposta più lunga del necessario :)

Comment: Jeffrey, sono perfettamente d'accordo sull'uso di “spendere” e “spendibile” in questo contesto, ma forse non del tutto sulla dinamica di chi ha quali aspettative da Parigi etc. (ma anche il testo originale non mi è chiarissimo). A quel che capisco, il marito Francesco ha sentito dai commilitoni (e quindi forse in caserma più che nei salotti) storie di donnine e scommesse, e questo fa sì che gli interessino di meno i viali, i caffè e altre esperienze più accettabili nella buona società.

Comment: @DaG: Hai sicuramente ragione, ho fatto un bel volo pindarico sul passaggio breve per analizzare il verbo in questione, senza sapere niente sulla storia e quindi di sicuro dicendo un mucchio di idiozie `:)` In questo caso, lui considera le classiche viste che uno si aspetta da Parigi come meri souvenir, e vuole invece vivere emozioni più spinte che poco hanno a che vedere col turismo architettonico.

Comment: Jeffrey, usa "@nome" se vuoi che un utente riceva una notifica di un tuo commento. L'ho aggiunto io come moderatrice, così puoi vedere come si fa. Se vuoi, puoi modificare la tua risposta con la funzione "Edit". Io sto leggendo il romanzo, ma non so niente di più di questi amici di Francesco.

Comment: @Charo Grazie, ultimamente avevo l'impressione fosse una cosa puramente formale per far capire a chi stavi parlando, non avevo capito avesse un effetto tecnico. A buon rendere! `:)`

Comment: Neanch'io so niente del romanzo, Jeffrey (rispondendo a una tua domanda o risposta, come vedi, non è necessario il @): dicevo solo come l'avevo interpretato io. Poi magari @Charo ce lo chiarirà se più avanti se ne dice di più.

Comment: @DaG Credo che abbia interpretato meglio di me, infatti. Non sapevo cosa farmene della "Cavalleria". Tu invece hai capito che si tratta di un reparto militare. A volte tengo 'a capa sulo pe spartere ê rrecchje (lezione di folklore, dialetti e modi di dire Italiani `:)`)